# Grouped Barplot in R for a matrix of a data frame

Tags: r, bar-chart

I m a novice in R
I want to plot grouped bar plot
to get the data I used

```
pch<-as.matrix(data.frame(for_Rch13$Ch1to11,for_Rch13$Ch1to13))
rownames(bch) <- c("Ch1", "Ch2","Ch3","Ch4","Ch5","Ch6","Ch7","Ch8","Ch9","Ch10", "Ch11","Ch12","Ch13")
pch
       for_Rch13.Ch1to11 for_Rch13.Ch1to13
Ch1               9218              5360
Ch2               2661              2144
Ch3               1260               965
Ch4               1536              1884
Ch5               2793              3076
Ch6               5100              3370
Ch7               8845             12858
Ch8               1034              1743
Ch9               2057              1039
Ch10              1831              2413
Ch11              7285              8615
Ch12                 0              1369
Ch13                 0               968
```

Now when I did

```
barplot(pch, beside=TRUE)
```

Im getting a plot like this
[Barchart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgtbe.png)
I was hoping to get a grouped Bar
Please help

Comment: Try `barplot(pch~rownames(pch), beside=TRUE)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution!!
we need to transpose the matrix

```
>bch<-t(bch)
>bch
                 Ch1  Ch2  Ch3  Ch4  Ch5  Ch6   Ch7  Ch8  Ch9 Ch10 Ch11
for_Rch13.Ch1to11 9218 2661 1260 1536 2793 5100  8845 1034 2057 1831 7285
for_Rch13.Ch1to13 5360 2144  965 1884 3076 3370 12858 1743 1039 2413 8615
                  Ch12 Ch13
for_Rch13.Ch1to11    0    0
for_Rch13.Ch1to13 1369  968
>barplot(pch, besides=TRUE)
```

[image]